# how to read column in excel sheet using perl

Tags: perl

I have an excel sheet with 5 columns, in which I want details of column C.
below is my code, which I tried

```
use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft Excel';
use Spreadsheet::Read;
use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;
my $parser   = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel->new();
my $workbook = $parser->parse('abc.xls');
my $sheet_got;
for my $worksheet ( $workbook->worksheets() ) 
{
    my ( $row_min, $row_max ) = $worksheet->row_range();
    my ( $col_min, $col_max ) = $worksheet->col_range();
    for my $row ( $row_min .. $row_max ) 
    {
        for my $col ( $col_min .. $col_max ) 
        {
           my $cell = $worksheet->get_cell( $row, $col );
           next unless $cell;
           $cell = $cell->value();
           $sheet_got .= "$cell ";               
           }           
         }
     }
```

Comment: Please format your code using the editor toolbar. It is not readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for my $row ( $row_min .. $row_max ) 
    {
        for my $col ( $col_min .. $col_max ) 
        {
           my $cell = $worksheet->get_cell( $row, $col );
           next unless $cell;
           $cell = $cell->value();
           $sheet_got .= "$cell ";               
           }           
    }
```

Which clearly states that you are reading all values of excel file.
Mention the column you need to extract,

Try like this,

say excel data like,

Name - Age - Gender - Result

jack    - 21 -  M -     ok  - PASS

dane    - 32    - M -   ok  - PASS

stuart  - 45    - M - ok    - PASS

jane    65  F   ok  PASS

po  - 24    - M - ok    - PASS

So here column C is, Gender, so the result should be M M F M

```
use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft Excel';
use Spreadsheet::Read;
use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;
my $parser   = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel->new();
my $workbook = $parser->parse('test.xls');
my $sheet_got;
for my $worksheet ( $workbook->worksheets() ) 
{
my ( $row_min, $row_max ) = $worksheet->row_range();
my $col = 2;
for (;$row_min<$row_max;)
    {
        my $cell = $worksheet->get_cell( $row_min, $col );
        next unless $cell;
        $cell = $cell->value();
        $sheet_got .= "$cell ";
        $row_min = $row_min + 1;
    }
}
print $sheet_got;
```

The output will be,

```
>perl parseexcelsample.pl
M M M F
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try increment.

```
my $i;
for my $col ( $col_min .. $col_max ) {
    my $cell = $worksheet->get_cell( $row, $col );
    if (!$cell) {
        $i++;
        next;
    }
    $cell = $cell->value();
    $sheet_got .= "$cell " if ($i == 2);
    $i++;         
}
```